# SU hits 50000 questions.

Tags: discussion, questions

I've just spotted that, according to the [questions tab](https://superuser.com/questions), SU has now surpassed **50000 questions**!
<sub>And what's worrying is that I've posted an answer on just over ~0.2% (or 1/500<sup>th</sup>) of them...</sub>

For comparison SO is nearing 900k (wow!) and SF is just behind with 45k.

So, anyway, do we get extra presents to go with the birthday competition?
Or do we have to reach a better milestone first?
Maybe 65535?

<sup>I'm aware this is off topic, but if I'm going to post my *first ever* off topic post it might as well be for something (sort of) important. And hidden away on meta...</sup>

Comment: Pwned! xD Just a few more characters...

Comment: Indeed, so much for extra presents... D:

Comment: how is this off topic on meta SU? It's not!

Comment: Well, it did feel a bit `always-friday-in-iceland` -ish (even thought it was actually Friday..), and doesn't *really* have an answer. Possibly it should have been closed as too localized instead, because it's already out of date?